# Android Studio - In-app change theme buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

hope you are having a wonderful day!

So I'm creating a somewhat basic application in Android Studio, but I am no beginner. I want to give the users the ability to change the theme of the application at the press of a button and followed this guide somewhat: http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html

But I did made some changes myself. The problem I have right now is that when I use the black theme, the background turns black (correct), the textColor changes to white (correct) but the text color of my radio buttons and the buttons themselves stay black and are impossible to see.

**How do I change the color of the radio buttons and the radio button texts at the same time as I change the background/normal textColor?**

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- White theme -->
    <style name="WhiteTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <!-- Black theme -->
    <style name="BlackTheme" >
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Blue theme -->
    <style name="BlueTheme" >
        <item name="android:background">#B0E0E6</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Pink theme -->
    <style name="PinkTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#FF69B4</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**EU.xml** (Where the radio buttons are used)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.zzz.EU">

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </RadioGroup>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/EUManRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/EUManRadioButtonString"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/EUWomanRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/EUWomanRadioButtonString"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EUManRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EUManRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EUManRadioButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangeTheme"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_theme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**ChangeTheme.java**

```
package com.example.xxx.zzz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class ChangeTheme extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_theme);
}

public void onClickChangeThemeBack(View view){
    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i1);
}

public void onClickNormalTheme(View view){
//Placeholder BLACK    
themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLACK);
}

public void onClickBlackTheme(View view){
    themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLACK);
}

public void onClickBlueTheme(View view){
    themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLUE);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_u, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_change_theme.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.zzz.ChangeTheme">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ChangeThemeBackButtonString"
    android:id="@+id/ChangeThemeBackButton"
    android:onClick="onClickChangeThemeBack"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ChangeThemeButtonString"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="onClickChangeThemeBack"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ChangeThemeBackButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ChangeThemeNormalButtonString"
    android:id="@+id/ChangeThemeNormalButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClickNormalTheme" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ChangeThemeBlackButtonString"
    android:id="@+id/ChangeThemeBlackButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChangeThemeNormalButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClickBlackTheme" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ChangeThemeBlueButtonString"
    android:id="@+id/ChangeThemeBlueButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChangeThemeBlackButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClickBlueTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**themeUtils.java**

```
package com.example.xxx.zzz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class themeUtils
{
    private static int cTheme;
    public final static int WHITE = 0;
    public final static int BLACK = 1;
    public final static int BLUE = 2;
    public final static int PINK = 3;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        cTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (cTheme)
        {
            default:
            case WHITE:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.WhiteTheme);
                break;
            case BLACK:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
                break;
            case BLUE:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                break;
            case PINK:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.PinkTheme);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to every theme you wish to provide to the user at values/styles.xml or wherever is your theme file

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   <resources>
> <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
>      <!-- Widget styles -->
>      <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Spinner</item>
>      <item      name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner </item>
>      <item   name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem </item>
> </style>
> ```